# Error adding foreign key constraint in Laravel - migrations in right order

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, migration

Here is the issue.  I am familiar with how key constraints are supposed to work in Laravel.  I have also researched this problem thoroughly and tried many solutions to no avail.  I have a couple of migrations that look like this, and are run in the order you see:

```
public function up()
14   {
15     Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
16       $table->engine='InnoDB';
17       $table->increments('id');
18       $table->string('customer_first_name');
19       $table->string('customer_last_name');
20       $table->string('street_address_1');
21       $table->string('street_address_2');
22       $table->string('city');
23       $table->string('state', '2');
24       $table->integer('zip');
25       $table->string('region');
26       $table->string('customer_email')->unique();
27       $table->integer('added_by');
28       $table->timestamps();
29     });
30   }
```

---

```
public function up()
14   {
15     Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
16       $table->engine='InnoDB';
17       $table->increments('id');
18       $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
19       $table->foreign('customer_id')
20         ->references('id')->on('customers')->onDelete('cascade');
21       $table->string('service');
22       $table->text('service_description');
23       $table->date('service_date');
24       $table->integer('reminder_sent');
25       $table->tinyInteger('review_posted');
26       $table->string('token');
27       $table->timestamps();
28     });
29   }
```

I have a number of software installs that ran these migrations without issue within the last few months.  But when trying to install today, the services migration failed (repeatedly) with the following message:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'gen_hometown3
.#sql-6ef_19b6c' (errno: 121) (SQL: alter table `sr_client_services` ad
d constraint `services_customer_id_foreign` foreign key (`customer_id`) ref
erences `sr_client_customers` (`id`) on delete cascade)


[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'gen_hometown3
.#sql-6ef_19b6c' (errno: 121)
```

I have attempted to move the key constraint declarations to the end of the table creation, into a separate Schema::table() block, made the foreign key nullable() (and then reversed that change) and flipped the order of migrations around, but the error persists.  The migrations run (there are others that come before, nut none have foreign keys) right up until the services table, and then I get the error described above.

What is *really* puzzling me is that I've run these same migrations before (not long ago), on this same server, without issue.

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance.

Comment: It wasn't quite a duplicate of that question, but I found the answer in the thread.  There was a constraint already in the database with the name the new migration was attempting to use.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the dupe doesn't solve the problem, you can always disable foreign key checks altogether for the migration:

```
public function up()
    DB::statement("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0");
    Schema::create("services", ...);
    DB::statement("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1");
}
```